# Matching against a specific URL in Javascript with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to invoke some Javascript only if I'm on a specific URL with a random subdomain: `https://*.testsite123.io/testsite123/portal/#/login`. So far I came up with

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  var escaped = str.replace(/([.+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
  console.log("escaped " + escaped);
  escaped = new RegExp(escaped);
  return escaped;
}
function matchUrl() {
  var currentUrl = window.location.toString();
  var loginUrlRegex = escapeRegExp("https://*.testsite123.io/testsite123/portal/#/login");
  return loginUrlRegex.test(currentUrl);
}

console.log("window.location " + window.location.toString());
console.log("match " + matchUrl());
```

Executed in the chrome console while on `https://prod.testsite123.io/testsite123/portal/#/login` this yields:

```
window.location https://prod.testsite123.io/testsite123/portal/#/login
escaped https\:\/\/*\.testsite123\.io\/testsite123\/portal\/#\/login
match false
```

I don't know why they don't match? I've escaped everything except the `*`?

Comment: use RegExp literals to avoid all the confusing escaping  problems

Comment: When you say *"specific url"* at what point did `*` become anything close to specific? `https://*.`???

Comment: @dandavis My URL has `/` and  `#` so I don't know with any other literals I should escape it.

Comment: @zer00ne sorry I meant specific url with random subdomain. the subdomain is the only thing that changes. I've updated the question.

Comment: You should try adding a dot+question mark to the asterisk like so: `*.?` this will make it "lazy" meaning it'll accept whatever is `*` up until it sees the `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to escape a regular expression in JavaScript ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/3233827)):

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
   return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

In your regex string, you included a `*`, probably as a placeholder for a substring. You need to use a correct regex variant, e.g. `[^\.]+`.

Furthermore, you are escaping the (incorrect) `*` also in the `escape()` function. You need to escape everything except the actual regular expression pattern. So an example for this would be:

```
var regexString = escapeRegExp("https://") + '[^\\.]+' + escapeRegExp(".testsite123.io/testsite123/portal/#/login");
var regex = new RegExp(regexString);
var result = regex.test(window.location.toString());

console.log(result);
```

*In the example above, I used `[^\\.]+` instead of `[^\.]+`. This escaping is only because it would result in a JavaScript error if you use an unescaped `\` in a JavaScript string. The content of the JavaScript string is then `[^\.]+` (only one `\`). This is **not** the same escaping as the regular expression escaping above.*

Answer (score 0):

@ssc-hrep3 almost. The escaping is correct. The test should be the regex Object with the string, not the string with the regex Object. If you change your answer I will mark it as solution.

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

function matchUrl() {
  var currentUrl = window.location.toString();
  var loginUrl =
    escapeRegExp("https://") +
    '[^\\.]+' +
    escapeRegExp(".testsite123.io/testsite123/portal/#/login");
  loginUrl = new RegExp(loginUrl);

  return result = loginUrl.test(currentUrl);
}

if (matchUrl()) {
  //doStuff()
}
```